# Force a Core Data Checkpoint?

Tags: ios, core-data

I write an app that churns a great deal of data through Core Data. I clean up this data after the user has exited the app in the background. Because WAL checkpointing appears to be a major cause of my UI pauses, I would like to also force a WAL checkpoint. (Yes, I know about creating a second Core Data stack. That will also be done but this problem will still remain. I have existing experiments using a second stack but they haven't yet resulted in any appreciable advantage.) The Google reveals the following page, [New Default Journaling Mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1809/_index.html), which goes into a very modest discussion of how to force a checkpoint of a database before copying it elsewhere. My issue is I would like to force the checkpoint on the live database without tearing down my whole UI. My experiments re-adding the persistent store to the coordinator are to no avail. They result in an infinite loop.

Clearly, checkpointing can be done without affecting my existing MOCs and PSC because it already happens. I just want to force it at a well known time that doesn't affect my user's happiness.

Comment: How are you verifying that this is the cause of UI pauses?

Comment: I'm verifying this by interrupting the app during the many second pause and seeing that the app is in the middle of a background save. Since SQLite is single threaded, the UI is hitting that save and is blocked. (You can tell this because the main thread is down in the CD stack too.) Do you need more info?

Comment: I guess you read [THIS](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) and tried lowering [THAT](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_wal_checkpoint) in your store pragma options. That said, it does sound like you are doing a huge write operation on your store (hundreds of objects being deleted at once). if you are to segment the operation into smaller chunks of deleted objects you might avoid this contention altogether.

Answer (score 2):

That document's description may be modest, but that's how it's done. Core Data isn't really a SQLite wrapper, and it provides very limited direct access to SQLite. Passing options when adding the persistent store is the only option.

In short: you can't force a checkpoint on a live persistent store.

What you can do is use that method all the time, changing to rollback journal mode all the time instead of only for checkpoint purposes. By using the `journal_mode` option, you can switch SQLite to a different mode where checkpointing isn't needed. As long as you include

```
NSDictionary *options = @{NSSQLitePragmasOption:@{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"}};
```

when adding the store, the problem doesn't exist.

If you want to retain `wal` mode, you can try using other SQLite pragmas in the option list to tune the checkpointing behavior. For example, the `wal_autocheckpoint` pragma tunes how often checkpoints occur. You might be able to get better results by adjusting that. You still can't invoke a checkpoint on demand, but you'll change the performance.

Comment: how about this: to force checkpoint create new NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with the DELETE journal_mode   that links to our store. Would this work?