# Is it possible to perform CoreData WAL checkpoint to "merge" everything into a single SQLite file?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data

3 files are generated when using CoreData

```
xxx.sqlite
xxx.sqlite-shm
xxx.sqlite-wal
```

Since our app has a feature, to export the SQLite file, we would like to perform WAL checkpoint on demand, to "merge" WAL & SHM into .sqlite file.

We thought by "closing" the opened database should be able to accomplish such.

We tried

```
func forceWALCheckpointingForStore() {
    do {
        let persistentStoreCoordinator = persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator

        let stores = persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores

        for store in stores {
            try persistentStoreCoordinator.remove(store)
        }
    } catch {
        error_log(error)
    }
}
```

3 files are still visible instead of 1 .sqlite file

Based on an answer 7 years ago - [Force a Core Data Checkpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822025/force-a-core-data-checkpoint) It seems that it is not possible to achieve so via CoreData.

I was wondering, is it possible in to-date? Is it possible to perform CoreData WAL checkpoint to "merge" everything into a single SQLite file?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use [migratePersistentStore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22672386/2378643) to create a copy of the database?